# SQLAlchemy: Querying members of one-to-many relationships whose parents are members of a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm building an event planner app with Flask, and I'm trying to write a function that returns all events that are visible to the current user. These include:

- The user's own events
- All public events
- Friends-only events that belong to the user's friends
- Invite-only events that the user has been invited to/has RSVP'd to

Here are the relevant models and tables:

```
friendship = db.Table('friendships', db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column('a_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('b_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    events = db.relationship('Event', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    
    friends = db.relationship('User',
            secondary=friendship,
            primaryjoin=id==friendship.c.a_id,
            secondaryjoin=id==friendship.c.b_id,
            lazy='dynamic')
    
    # Filter in case event privacy has been updated
    def associated_events(self, user=None):
        return self.invited_events\
            .union(self.going_events)\
            .union(self.not_going_events)\
            .filter(~Event.privacy == 1)

# going and not_going are virtually identical
invited = db.Table('invited_users_table', db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column('event_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('events.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class Event(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    #   1 - private, 2 - invite only, 3 - friends only, 4 - public
    privacy = db.Column(db.Integer, default=1)
    
    # going_users and not_going_users are virtually identical
    invited_users = db.relationship('User',
                        secondary=invited,
                        backref=db.backref('invited_events', lazy='dynamic'),
                        lazy='dynamic')
```

I've written a function that *works*, but it's very slow and admittedly hacked together through hours of trial and error:

```
def visible_events():
    # Public events
    result = Event.query.filter(Event.privacy == 4)
    
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        result = result.union_all(
                # Own events
                current_user.events,
                # Invited/RSVP'd events
                current_user.associated_events(),
                # Friends' events
                Event.query.filter(Event.privacy == 3)
                    .join(User, Event.author)
                    .join(friendship, friendship.c.a_id == User.id)
                    .filter(friendship.c.b_id == current_user.id)
                )
    
    return result
```

Is there a better way to approach this function, or perhaps the underlying classes and tables? Thank you!

Comment: This is the exact reason I just write queries in my code and call sql, and bypass ORM's all together.

Comment: @eatmeimadanish I see. I've actually never written SQL, and prior to this project I'd never worked with a database at all. I'm sorry, but do you have any suggestions for writing such a complex query?